# Find all PEAR packages needed in project (source code)

Tags: php, composer-php, pear, usage-statistics

I have come across an issue for which I need a list of all PEAR packages which are needed (=used) in my project.
Is there a tool which can get me a list of all PEAR packages used in my source code, by simply reading the code?
Read all the packages which are installed is not enough, I really need just those which are really used.
I need this so I can upgrade the packages, or better - replace them by new libraries installable through composer.

I came across the PEAR package [PHP_CompatInfo](http://php5.laurent-laville.org/compatinfo) but this does not give me good results, and it also does only list packages which are registred in the plugin itself.

Comment: What version of PHP are you running?

Comment: I am running PHP 5.3. but if it helps I can upgrade to any 5.x version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would first assess what PEAR classes are installed on the system

if you think that some of Libs used in the project may be missing, you need to download locally whole Pear repository

to download all packages execute:

```
pear config-set preferred_state alpha
pear remote-list | awk '{print $1}' > tmp-list ; tail -n +5 tmp-list > pear-list ; rm tmp-list
cat pear-list | xargs -n 1 pear install
```

Then to create a list of all classes:

```
cd /usr/share/php #( or different path to pear libs )

find . ! -path "*/tests/*" ! -path "*/examples/*" -name "*.php" -type f | xargs grep -Pho "^class ([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)" | sed -e "s/^class //" -e "" > all_pear.txt
```

That would create a list of all Pear classes saved into `all_pear.txt`

Then I would search for all references in my code

```
cd my_project;

while read line; do find . -name "*.php" -type f | xargs grep -Pho $line; done < path/to/all_pear.txt | sort | uniq > used_classes.txt
```

That will create list off all PEAR classes used in the project and it saves the list into file `used_classes.txt`

Comment: seem to be be a nice solution, however - you need all pear libs downloaded first + I still get some weird packages like "C" or "abc", "d" which I have no idea about

Comment: It could be that these "a" "b" classes are coming from tests directories I updated answer and excluded both tests and examples directories. Also added basic instructions how to download all pear classes..  ( still during download some libs  shows that some PHP extensions are missing ), so probably there should be a better way to download all packages without dependencies check.

Comment: I basically do not like the idea much that I have to pollute my system with installing all pear packages just to search in them. But I guess in my case I do not need to, as my application works, so I assume that all libraries which I need are already installed. I just want to filter out those I do not need